# React-Native error on deployment update in google playstore, lib hermes

Tags: java, react-native

after update only this error happens:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application de.*****.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: could not delete: /data/user/0/de.*****/lib-0/libhermes.so
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6996)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:257)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1982)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: could not delete: /data/user/0/de.*****/lib-0/libhermes.so
> at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init(SoLoader.java:214)
> at de.*****.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:61)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6991)
> ... 8 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: could not delete: /data/user/0/de.*****/lib-0/libhermes.so
> at com.facebook.soloader.SysUtil.dumbDeleteRecursive(SysUtil.java:119)
> at com.facebook.soloader.UnpackingSoSource.deleteUnmentionedFiles(UnpackingSoSource.java:207)
> at com.facebook.soloader.UnpackingSoSource.regenerate(UnpackingSoSource.java:264)
> at com.facebook.soloader.UnpackingSoSource.refreshLocked(UnpackingSoSource.java:321)
> at com.facebook.soloader.UnpackingSoSource.prepare(UnpackingSoSource.java:414)
> at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.initSoSources(SoLoader.java:322)
> at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init(SoLoader.java:200)
> at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init(SoLoader.java:182)
> at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init(SoLoader.java:212)

What could be the cause?
I added hermes-engine 0.7.2 before, *package.json*:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.10",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.6",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "^43.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~10.1.3",
    "expo-file-system": "~13.0.3",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.13.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.13",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-annotation": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-share": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with respect to react-native.
It has been resolved in the version RN 0.68.0

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32735) to the thread.

So i kindly recommend you to update React-Native version.